# pandas: how to subset row with 'False' value before the 'true' value in a column regarding to each group in other column

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I'd like to ask about subsetting data frame

suppose i have data frame like

```
|index |name|buy|
--------------
0   a   False

1   a   True

2   b   False

3   c   True

4   b   False

5   a   False

6   c   True

7   c   False
```

the question is how to subset row with `False` value before the `true` value in a column (in this case `buy` column) regarding to each group in other column (in this case `name` column)

the demanded result is like that

```
|index |name|buy|
--------------
0   a   False

2   b   False

4   b   False
```

i tried it by subsetting data frame by each `name` then use `np.where` the find the first true then subset and concat them back, but i found it very slow

is there more efficient way to do that?

Comment: Can't see your data: please post it in your question as `code` (i.e. not images).

Comment: Thanks @cmaher i'm new about it. i've edit it into text

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way that comes to mind:

1: grab the index of rows where `buy` is `True` and then subtract one to get the index value for each `False` row prior

```
target_ix = dframe[dframe[dframe.buy==True].index + 1
```

2: then use target_ix to subset your DataFrame

```
dframe.iloc[target_ix,:]
```